# Prestashop 1.6: where is category image stored?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I write a script to import categorys in my new prestashop project, i must do it because of complex data structure, i imported at this moment everything without any problems, but i can not find where is category image stored? I created a test installation with 1 category and image, but i can not find where is this image in database stored?

Until now i used following tables:

```
ps_category
ps_category_shop
ps_category_group
ps_category_lang
```

I read also more times prestashop documentation, a example is [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CSV+Import+Parameters)

Answer (score 4):

The category images are not stored in the database. They are generated in the /img/c/ folder.

Comment: Is there any way to change it? Because we get also image file names with our data structure?

Comment: You need to import them with the PrestaShop "framework", take a look a the import file structure and you will see how to add them.

Answer (score 2):

The url of image is created when you upload a image of product or category. It is something like `your-site.com/img/p/id_of_product/size_id/number.type` for category `your-site.com/img/c/id_of_category/size_id/number.type`.

Even it is not saved in anywhere in database, as you can see all the things are identical to a product or category. It can be derived. So you might also use the same technique for your use.